# Get a mesh from a frame of a MeshSequenceCache in script

Tags: python, vertices, cache, alembic

As the title says, I need help to understand how to access individual meshes from an object with a mesh sequence cache modifier that was created by importing an alembic animation. I want to access it with the blender python library, so that I can write a plugin to make the process easier in the future.

The end goal is to get each vertex of each face of the sequence to map generated faces onto, to write into a vertex animation texture in the end.

Comment: if the mesh sequence cache modifier was applied...you would access it like any other mesh of an object in python....

Comment: Ok let me correct myself then, the modifier is not applied, but it is active otherwise I would just get one frame of the mesh animation